# Spending key hash vs payment key hash (pkh)

Tags: plutus, address

Cardano speaks in its documentation of the 'spending key hash' (see e.g. here: https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-addresses/demo/). In Plutus there is no spending key, there is a `PaymentPubKeyHash` in `Ledger.Address`. Are these the same ?

Comment: I found no `PaymentPubKeyHash`, but, from what I know, `PubKeyHash` is the same as spending key hash

Comment: PaymentPubKeyHash is a wrapper around PubKeyHash that was introduced recently to have more type safety and not confound stake and payment key. You can find it defined here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-ledger/src/Ledger/Address.hs

Comment: Interesting... Actually, I think "spending key" is the same as "private key", but "verification key" the same as "public key", so "spending key hash" would probably be "private key hash"